# Time of flight of a javelin

Tags: physics

> An athlete throws a javelin at an angle of $45^{\circ}$ to the  horizontal and, after a time interval $t$, the javelin hits the ground $16$ $\text{m}$ in front of the throwing point . Neglecting the air resistance and the athlete's height, the time interval $t$, in
> seconds, is a value closer to? (given $\sin 45^{\circ} = \cos 45^{\circ} = 0.7$)

**Attempt:** We have that $v_x=v_y=0.7 v$. For reach (assuming that the throw has symmetrical height and reach at the same level) the reach it took the ball to reach the maximum height will be equal to the total reach, so $$8 = v_{0_x} t \implies t = \frac{0.8}{0.7 v_0}$$ Now, at the maximum height we have that $$0 = v_{0_y} - 10 t \implies t = \frac{40 \sqrt{5}}{7}$$  So the time will be $2t = \frac{80 \sqrt{5}}{7}$ The answer to this question is $16$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: $\cos 45^{\circ} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\ne 0.7$

Comment: @markvs I know, but in the statement it was considered as this strange value

Comment: @markvs $\frac{\sqrt 2}2=0.707\approx 0.7$

Comment: @Andrei: $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\ne 0.707$  either.

Comment: @markvs it is a little more. How many digits do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have (assuming $g=9.8\  m/s^2$):

$$d_x = v_{0x}t$$
$$d_y = v_{0y}t-4.9t^2$$

Setting $d_y$ to zero (where the javelin is at the horizontal axis) gives $t=0,\dfrac{v_{0y}}{4.9}$. Clearly it is the positive value. Then

$$16=d_x = v_{0x}t=v_{0x}\cdot \dfrac{v_{0y}}{4.9} = \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}v_0\right)^2}{4.9}=\dfrac{v_0^2}{9.8}$$

So $$v_0 = \sqrt{16\cdot 9.8}$$
$$t = \dfrac{d_x}{v_{0x}} = \dfrac{16}{{\sqrt{2}\over {2}} \cdot \sqrt{16\cdot 9.8}}\approx 1.807$$

You will arrive at a similar result using $0.7$ instead of $\sqrt 2\over 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Neither your result, nor the given values are realistic. $16$ seconds is a very long time. One can use the distance along the horizontal and along the vertical:$$d=v_0\cos 45^\circ t\\0=v_0\sin 45^\circ t-\frac12 gt^2\\
t=\sqrt{\frac{2d}g}\approx 1.8
$$